# При разных запросах - один ответ

Tags: php

Не могу понять в чем ошибка, при запросе setup_server выводит Сервер установлен, как и должно быьь, но при запросе get_users пишет то же самое, хотя должна выводить список юзеров.

```
<?php

$act = $_GET['act'];
$command = $_GET['command'];
$parameter = $_GET['value'];

if ($act="setup_server"){
  if ( !file_exists( "users.txt" ) ){
    touch( "users.txt" );
    echo "Сервер установлен";
    exit;
  }
  else{
    echo "Сервер установлен";
    exit;
  }
}

if (($act="get_users") && (file_exists( "users.txt" ))){
  $f_users = fopen( "users.txt", "r" ) or die ( "Не удалось открыть файл" );
  $first=true;
  while ( !feof ( $f_users ) ){
    if ($first==true){
    $all_users=( fgets( $f_users , 1024 ) )."|";
    $first=false;
  } 
  else {
    $all_users .= ( fgets( $f_users , 1024 ) )."|";
  }
} 
echo $all_users;
exit;
} else {
  echo "Файл не найден";
  exit;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из-за присваивания. Замените "=" на "==".
if ($act=="setup_server"){..}
if (($act=="get_users") ...

Сейчас вы присваиваете $act всё время значение "setup_server".

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вот это:

```
$act="setup_server"
```

возвращает TRUE и выполняется первое условие.